# Grouping Cubes into Larger Cubes to minimize Total Number of Cubes

Tags: algorithm, optimization, 3d, reduction, cubes

I'm trying to find an optimal solution for this sort of problem.

Essentially, I have a grid of squares that could look something like this:
[image: Box Grouping Start]

And I want an algorithm that can turn it into something like this:

[image: Box Grouping End]

However, this is technically a 3D problem, and there are some special cases where not all squares are required (meaning I won't always need 4 squares to form a larger square, or 8 cubes to form a larger cube).

The above will always apply in 3D (if 8 cubes are found, make a larger 2x2 cube). The special cases occur when faces are hidden, like so:

[image: Cube Grouping Start]

*(Hidden Area has no cube)*

[image: Cube Grouping End]

There's a few things to note here:

- 3 Cubes *correctly* turned into one larger Cube
- Downward expansion *does not matter*, and is preferred if it means fewer cubes
- If the Cube on the higher level were not there, this solution would require a Cube in the hidden/empty space

To make matters worse, there's yet another restriction: Cube sizes range from 1 to 64, and must be a power of 2 (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, and 64 only).

I'm simply looking for pseudo-code or a laymen term's explanation. I will be implementing this via code, but I want to solve this problem using logic first.

**Note:** A problem like this can have many solutions. I would prefer to have an optimal solution, but I'm really just trying to reduce the number of Cubes I have as much as possible. Anything that is useful would be appreciated (like a known algorithm that already does something similar to this).